# Configuring Secure Web Socket on Amazon Beanstalk

Tags: nginx, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've deployed two Node.js apps on Amazon Beanstalk: one is the frontend developed with React and running with [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve), the other is [an MQTT broker](https://github.com/mcollina/aedes) with a web socket handler.
Load balancer is nginx 1.12.1, with this configuration (written inside `.ebextension` folder of the backend project):

```
  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
      default upgrade;
      '' close;
  }

  upstream websocket {
      server 127.0.0.1:5000;
  }

  server {
    listen 8080;

    if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
        set $year $1;
        set $month $2;
        set $day $3;
        set $hour $4;
    }
    access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass  "http://127.0.0.1:3003";

        proxy_redirect off;

        # Socket.IO Support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
    }

    location /subscriptions {
        proxy_pass http://websocket;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  }
```

The frontend should be able to consume `wss://mqtt_url/subscriptions`, but with whatever configuration I use, I always get `WebSocket is closed before the connection is established`. This configuration seems to work with non-secure web socket consumption.
The server waiting for connections is just a simple HTTP server like this:

```js
const server = createServer();

server.listen(5000, '0.0.0.0', () =>
  new SubscriptionServer({
        execute,
        subscribe,
        schema,
        onConnect: async (connectionParams) => {

        },
  }, {
        server,
        path: '/subscriptions',
  }));
```

Beanstalk load balancing is configured like the following:

- Port: TCP on port 80
- Port: 80
- Secure port: SSL on port 443 Secure
- port: 443
- Health: TCP pings on port 80
- Cross zone load balancing is enabled
- Connection draining is enabled with 200 seconds timeout

Searching around for information, I was just able to see that it's good to select TCP/SSL as protocol, but apart from that, it's not very clear how to configure WSS here.
Any suggestion will be appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your subscriptions location block

`proxy_read_timeout 86400;`