# Web socket connection does not work over SSL

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, web, websocket

I have Web Socket that works perfectly fine on localhost and production (https://www.example.com) environment.

However, when I deploy the same code to pp environment (https://pp.example.com) I get WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

I have AWS certificate manager generated certificate for domain example.com, with additional domain name www.example.com and pp.example.com

www.example.com and pp.example.com are sitting on **different server so they have different ip addresses**.

When I go to www.example.com and make the following call,

```
let ws = new WebSocket("wss://www.example.com/ws");
```

It works perfectly fine.web socket is connected.

However, when I switch to pp.example.com and make the following call

```
let ws = new WebSocket("wss://pp.example.com/ws");
```

I get error from Safari, Firefox and Chrome:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://pp.example.com/ws' failed: Error during
>   WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Any ideas?

The code are exactly the same.

They are deployed on aws beanstalk.

production environment is using global accelerator + application load balancer + EC2

pp environment is using classic load balancer + EC2

Comment: does [this](https://medium.com/@binyamin/node-websockets-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk-elastic-load-balancer-elb-or-application-load-6a693b21415a) or [this](https://nikhilmopidevi.github.io/2017/10/22/HTTPS-for-WebSockets-App-on-AWS/) help, and I can even see that [you're not the only one here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49011864/28004) asking for that... no experience on WebSockets, but I know plenty of AWS 

Comment: @balexandre Please! You are genius! Thank you for the help! The second link you gvie: https://nikhilmopidevi.github.io/2017/10/22/HTTPS-for-WebSockets-App-on-AWS/ resolve the problem! The problems lies in I configured classic load balancer port 443 listener with HTTPS instead of SSL TCP! Thanks!!

Comment: Google is our friend ✌ Remember to write here what you did, so the next person can see what needs to be done 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems lies in load balancer's listener.
I was using HTTPS for traffic forwarding, while web socket works on TCP level, therefore, it should be SSL TCP instead.

See the attached screenshot at the following for load balancer
[image]